# Insert javascript (jquery) variable in html input field (textbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `span` and `div` this works

### jQuery

```
$('#exchange_rate1').html(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);
```

### HTML

```
<span id="exchange_rate1"></span>
```

But if the HTML is an input element such as `<input type='text' name='exchange_rate1' id='exchange_rate1' value='<?php echo $post_exchange_rate; ?>>` then nothing happens.

Removed `php` code from `value` the same nothing.

I also tried `document.getElementById("exchange_rate1").html(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);` but I also see nothing.

Now clear, that need to use `val`. I just searched google for how to insert jquery variable in input field. Could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific:

```
// store the value you're looking to assign
var data = [
  { FinalCurrencyRate: <?= $post_echange_rate; ?> }
];
```

the jQuery way:

```
$('#exchange_rate1')               // grab the <input>
  .val(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate); // and assign it from the variable
```

the straight js way:

```
// normal JS version:
document.getElementById('exchange_rate1') // grab the <input>
  .value = data[0].FinalCurrencyRate;     // assign it
```

Any kind of form fields (`<input>`,`<select>`,`<textarea>`) use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get/set since they don't contain child elements. [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) should be used for structural elements.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`jQueryObject.val(some_value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value of an input, not `html()`.

Comment: But _why_ is that?!?! (teach a man to fish...) IMHO, SO should be more than a "Ask question"..."get answer"; too many people just post the solution without actually explaining _why_ the OP should do it that way, which is just going to result in _another_ question down the road for the same or similar problem. @ 250k rep, [you should know that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In case of `text` use as

```
$("#exchange_rate1").val('Hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you aren't supposed to be setting the `innerHTML` of the `input` element, but the `value`.

In jQuery you use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('#exchange_rate1').val(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);
```

Or with plain JavaScript, you're changing the `value` property of the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) object:

```
document.getElementById('exchange_rate1').value = data[0].FinalCurrencyRate;
```

Answer (score 1):

For textual input boxes, use `.val()`, for textareas, use `.text()`, and for non-input type elements, use `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
$("#exchange_rate1").val('Hello');
```

Comment: And if u want to fetch the data then $("#exchange_rate1").val();