# How to write a variable to an input field with javaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input box #bar inside of div #foo. The value of input box #bar is "bar"

```
<div id="foo">
    <input id="bar" type="text" name="bar" size="5" value="bar" style="width:200px"/>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to change the value of #bar from "bar" to "foobar".

I saw this question on stackoverflow: [Insert javascript (jquery) variable in html input field (textbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466008/insert-javascript-jquery-variable-in-html-input-field-textbox)

and tried the below jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fooBar = "foobar";
    $('#bar').val(data[0].fooBar);
});
```

I must be missing something. I tried searching google, but as the post above mentions it was not very helpful. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/18/) is a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Can you tell us why did you think `data[0].fooBar` should work

Comment: I am new to javascript. Did try to google, did search stackoverflow. Other stackoverflow post had data[0] in solution. Now I see that he must have been using an array somewhere. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable called `data`, you have a variable called `fooBar` just use it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fooBar = "foobar";
    $('#bar').val(fooBar);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A6Yev/)

Comment: This did work. The other poster must have been using the rest of the code for something else. Thank you!